# Automatically add value to column of new list item?

Tags: list, calculated-column, list-item

**How can I automatically add a value to a column when making a new list item?**

Like, if I make a new item in a list named "Announcements", and I want the "Expires" column to automatically get a date 3 months later than today's date, how would I do that? Or is this simply not possible?

Should I do this with a *calculated column*? Like, based on the date a list item was created/posted, extract that date and add 3 months?

Sorry for all these questions; I just can't figure it out.

I am ok with OOTB solutions, as long as I can do it with jQuery or JavaScript or anything similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do this with calculated column. Create one calculated column and set value as created date plus 3 months.

Comment: Thanks, I made the calculated column and for the formula I entered `=Created+90`.

Comment: Great. You can also use below formula:
=DATE(YEAR([Created]),MONTH([Created])+[3],DAY([Created])). refer below link for more details:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA010105479.aspx#BM2

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JQuery. Add a CEWP webpart to the page and add a script similar to this

```
$("input[tite='fieldName']").val("Value to prepopulate");
```

[SOURCE](http://sympmarc.com/2010/10/08/using-jquery-to-prefill-and-disable-required-column-in-a-sharepoint-form/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a more straight forward way to this. Just set the "Default Value" for the "Expired" column in the edit column page and set it to Today()+90